# How do i find the number of gangs in this question?

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Question) Let us define a gang of integers as integers that are formed by rearranging the digits in the decimal
representation of a positive integer. Example #1: 1123, 1213, 1231, 2113, 2131, 2311, 3112, 3121,
and 3211 form a gang. Example #2: 770, 707 and 077 form a gang.
Does there exist a gang, that is formed out of a 10-digit positive integer, in which we can find more
than 13000 10-digit positive integers that are multiples of 7? Explain your answer.

How do i find the number of 10 digit integers which are multiples of 7,
and how would i use the pigeonhole principle to solve this?

Comment: Example #1 has $(4 \times 3 = 12)$ gang members, since there are $4$ positions for the -3-, and then $3$ positions for the $2$.  Missing members are -1132-, -1312-, -1321-.  Similarly, the gang of $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots, 9\}$ has $9!$ gang members, which can routinely be converted into a $10$ digit number by forcing the rightmost digit to be $1$, so that the gang becomes $\{1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.  This 2nd gang has $\displaystyle \frac{10!}{2!} > 1,500,000$ gang members.  Typically, you would expect about $\displaystyle \frac{1}{7}$ of the gang members to be divisible by $7$. ...see next comment

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts. As a quick remark, if you start wih $9876543210$  there are $10!=3628800$ permutations, so if you figure that they are equi-distributed  $\pmod 7$ there would be more than $500000$ which are divisible by $7$.  Just as a place to start.

Comment: However, actually proving (perhaps by elegant enumeration) that the gang of $\{1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ has $> 13000$ members that are divisible by $7$ is a situation begging for some sort of elegance.  Here, my first try would be to google : "divisibility by 7", and see where this research leads.

Comment: @lulu Except: [1] unclear if leftmost digit can be $0$ and [2] finding some elegant demonstration (perhaps against my $\{1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ gang) may be somewhat onerous.

Comment: @user2661923  The OP uses $0$ as a lead digit explicitly.  And the OP has to start somewhere.

Comment: With respect to the answer of Clément Dato, the enumeration of $\binom{19}{10}$ comes from [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) which is also discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  The idea is that for $k \in \{1,2,3,\cdots, 10\}$, $x_k$ refers to the number of occurrences of $(k-1)$ in the gang of $10$ members.  Per Stars and Bars, $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{10} = 10 ~: x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{10} ~$ are all non-negative integers will have $$\binom{10 + [10-1]}{10 - 1}$$ distinct solutions.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question... (I've rolled back your edit.)

Answer (score 1):

The total number of 10-digit positive integers is $N=10^{10}$.

Among them, the number of those divisible by $7$ is $N_7=\lfloor N/7\rfloor(=1,428,571,428)$.

The total number of gangs formed by $10$-digit positive integers is $G={19\choose10}(=92,378)$.

By pigeonhole, we have at least one gang who contains more than $\lceil N_7/G\rceil=15465$ members divisible by $7$.

Comment: +1: very elegant.